# MySQL left JOIN, result if not all rows are set not working

Tags: mysql, left-join

I got the following query.
This should return a single row but it doesn't.

Unfortunately nothing.

When I remove the last join clause :

```
LEFT JOIN `serene_pagecontent` ON `serene_pageorder`.`pageorder_id` = `serene_pagecontent`.`pagecontent_link`
```

I do get a result. But when added it doesn't.
For as far as I know adding LEFT before join should deliver a result even if one of the fields is missing.

```
SELECT * FROM `serene_page`
LEFT JOIN `serene_pageoptions` ON `serene_page`.`page_id` = `serene_pageoptions`.`pageoptions_link`
LEFT JOIN `serene_pagetitle` ON `serene_page`.`page_id` = `serene_pagetitle`.`pagetitle_link`
LEFT JOIN `serene_pageorder` ON `serene_page`.`page_id` = `serene_pageorder`.`pageorder_link`
LEFT JOIN `serene_pagecontent` ON `serene_pageorder`.`pageorder_id` = `serene_pagecontent`.`pagecontent_link`
WHERE `page_id` = 34 AND `pageoptions_language` = 'NL' AND `pagetitle_language` = 'NL' AND `pagecontent_language` = 'NL'
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing.

**EDIT**

```
WHERE `serene_page`.`page_id` = 34 
  AND serene_pageoptions`.`pageoptions_language` = 'NL' 
  AND serene_pagetitle`.`pagetitle_language` = 'NL' 
  AND serene_pagecontent`.`pagecontent_language` = 'NL'
```

> **EDIT SOLUTION** :   *solution by "juergen d"*
>
> ```
>      SELECT * FROM `serene_page`
>
>      LEFT JOIN `serene_pageoptions` ON `serene_page`.`page_id` =`serene_pageoptions`.`pageoptions_link` AND
>  `serene_pageoptions`.`pageoptions_language` = 'NL'       
>   LEFT JOIN `serene_pagetitle` ON `serene_page`.`page_id` = `serene_pagetitle`.`pagetitle_link` AND
>  `serene_pagetitle`.`pagetitle_language` = 'NL'     
>
>      LEFT JOIN `serene_pageorder` ON `serene_page`.`page_id` = `serene_pageorder`.`pageorder_link` 
>
>
>      LEFT JOIN `serene_pagecontent` ON `serene_pageorder`.`pageorder_id` =
>  `serene_pagecontent`.`pagecontent_link` AND
>  `serene_pagecontent`.`pagecontent_language` = 'NL'
>
>      WHERE `serene_page`.`page_id` = 34
> ```
>
> I wasn't aware of the fact that I had to add the subclause if not
>   it  would turn to normal JOINS.    Thanks!!

Comment: What about the conditions in the `where` clause - are these columns of the joined tables?

Comment: Do you mean as editted?

Comment: There is no need to put the answer into the question. It just confuses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `left join` you need to put the conditions of the joined tables into the JOIN. Otherwise the LEFT JOINS turn into INNER JOINs

```
SELECT * 
FROM serene_page s
LEFT JOIN serene_pageoptions po  ON s.page_id = po.pageoptions_link
                                AND po.pageoptions_language = 'NL' 
LEFT JOIN serene_pagetitle pt    ON s.page_id = pt.pagetitle_link
                                AND pt.pagetitle_language = 'NL' 
LEFT JOIN serene_pageorder o     ON s.page_id = o.pageorder_link
LEFT JOIN serene_pagecontent c   ON o.pageorder_id = c.pagecontent_link
                                AND c.pagecontent_language = 'NL'
WHERE s.page_id = 34
```